# Magento 2 checkout input field validation possibility

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, form-validation, custom-field

I have searched in web two days how to validate checkout fields without any luck. All the research I have made have risen some questions because tutorials I have found are all about custom-form validation.

When I add additional fields to checkout step below or before shipping-method, inside already existing form and I want to validate them to be required. **Can I add only the fields needed or should I add the fields with form element?** All the tutorials and Magento 2 official documentation are teaching to validate forms but no where is any reason why forms should be used?

**Is it even possible to validated single input field inside Magento already existing form?** I know I can add input fields without form and get the information in admin section without any issues if the field can be left blank but otherwise.

***Example:*** I add the input field inside shipping method form below the radio buttons as additional field and I want alert to be raised when customer has not filled the field when `next` button is clicked?

**Additional questions (not required):** Can anyone suggest steps I should make to find out(debug...) how Magento 2 denies customer to go on, if required fields are not filled? I have tried chrome dev-tools, but i am beginner using it. How to find last executed if statement *(based on assumption)*?